# Japanese word for "Re-accommodate"

Tags: english-to-japanese

Thinking about the events concerning everyone's "favorite" airline United, I started to wonder what the Japanese word for "re-accommodate" was and 'oogle Translate wasn't much help.

Answer (score 3):

Though I couldn't find the exact translation, how about these?

> re-accommodation 振替｛ふりかえ｝／振替｛ふりか｝え／振｛ふ｝り替｛か｝え, re-accommodate 振｛ふ｝り替｛か｝える／振替｛ふりか｝える

This is an example using 振替｛ふりかえ｝.

> (事故｛じこ｝のとき)　振替輸送｛ふりかえゆそう｝をする
>   let passengers use alternative means of transportation without charge

The United Airlines may insist that;

> この度｛たび｝の件｛けん｝では、ユナイテッド航空｛こうくう｝は、単｛たん｝に、お客様｛きゃくさま｝に振替便｛ふりかえびん｝へのご搭乗｛とうじょう｝をお願｛ねが｝いしただけです。

Comment: IMO this answer is particularly good as you can use this verb to re-accommodate CEOs too :)

Answer (score 1):

In the UA context, how about   ご乗客様の選択なさった便を変更させていただきました？

Answer (score 0):

According to [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/accommodate) accommodate can be translated in various ways depending on the context.

I think you are interested in the first definition:

> 〈施設・乗り物などが〉〈人を〉収容する，乗せる，泊める.

I am not sure if there is a single word that includes the idea of "re"-accommodate, but one possibility in your case would be: 乗客{じょうきゃく}を再{ふたた}び収容{しゅうよう}する。

Ps. I'm trying to stay close to the context in your question and to give an answer as literally close as possible. Honestly though, I am not sure if in real life in that specific situation Japanese people would pick the word "accommodate" at all.

Comment: yeah, in Japanese they would probably use something totally different...